# iGraph + Plotly creates random connections

Tags: r, plotly, igraph, network-analysis

I'm trying to use the [example code here for doing `iGraph` network graphs in `plotly`](https://plot.ly/r/network-graphs/#new-to-plotly) and shoehorn in my own `data.frames` instead of using the example karate club data.  When the graph is plotted, it seems to ignore the edge list and a bunch of random connections are being made.  I think either the labels or edges are wrong but I can't tell.

```
library(igraph)
library(plotly)

setwd('C:/Users/Andrew Riffle/Documents/MEGAsync/code/R/link_analysis')

ID <- c(1:50)
nodes <- data.frame(ID)

Source <- c(23, 24, 36, 20, 36, 41, 12, 8, 18, 28)
Target <- c(5, 7, 9, 35, 23, 12, 38, 29, 33, 45)
links <- data.frame(Source, Target)

net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=FALSE)

net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T)

tkplot(net, vertex.label=nodes$id, vertex.label.color='white', layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold)

#####Begin plotly example code unmodified unless commented#####

G <- upgrade_graph(net) #put my iGraph object instead of the karate club one
L <- layout.circle(G)

vs <- V(G)
es <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(G))

Nv <- length(vs)
Ne <- length(es[1]$V1)

Xn <- L[,1]
Yn <- L[,2]

network <- plot_ly(x = ~Xn, y = ~Yn, mode = "markers", text = vs$name, hoverinfo = "text")

edge_shapes <- list()
for(i in 1:Ne) {
  v0 <- es[i,]$V1
  v1 <- es[i,]$V2

  edge_shape = list(
    type = "line",
    line = list(color = "#030303", width = 0.3),
    x0 = Xn[v0],
    y0 = Yn[v0],
    x1 = Xn[v1],
    y1 = Yn[v1]
  )

  edge_shapes[[i]] <- edge_shape
}

axis <- list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE)

p <- layout(
  network,
  title = 'Test Network', #Changed the title
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = axis,
  yaxis = axis
)

p #added a call to display p instead of upload to plot.ly
```

When I run this, I get [this nice pretty iGraph that has been plotted by `Plotly`](https://plot.ly/~andrewlriffle/1/).  However, the edges are incorrect.  It appears that only the ID's 1-10 are connecting, and only to other ID's less than 10.  None of these connections is in the edge list, which is below.

```
   Source Target
1      24     35
2      12     23
3      41     12
4      23      7
5      18      5
6      20      9
7      28     29
8      36     45
9       8     33
10     36     38
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a bit too late for the OP, but for the others who stumbled upon this same problem (as did I).

May I suggest the following five changes in the tutorial source code:

```
G <- upgrade_graph(net)
L <- layout.circle(G)
rownames(L) <- get.vertex.attribute(G)$name           #added line (#1 out of 5)

vs <- V(G)
es <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(G))

Nv <- length(vs)
Ne <- length(es[1]$V1)

Xn <- L[,1]
Yn <- L[,2]

network <- plot_ly(x = ~Xn, y = ~Yn, mode = "markers", text = vs$name, hoverinfo = "text")

edge_shapes <- list()
for(i in 1:Ne) {
  v0 <- es[i,]$V1
  v1 <- es[i,]$V2

  edge_shape = list(
    type = "line",
    line = list(color = "#030303", width = 0.3),
    x0 = L[which(v0==rownames(L)),][1],               #changed line (#2 out of 5)                
    y0 = L[which(v0==rownames(L)),][2],               #changed line (#3 out of 5)
    x1 = L[which(v1==rownames(L)),][1],               #changed line (#4 out of 5)
    y1 = L[which(v1==rownames(L)),][2]                #changed line (#5 out of 5)
  )

  edge_shapes[[i]] <- edge_shape
}

axis <- list(title = "", showgrid = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE)

p <- layout(
  network,
  title = 'Test Network', #Changed the title
  shapes = edge_shapes,
  xaxis = axis,
  yaxis = axis
)

p
```

Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that the tutorial is actually wrong.  If you plot the same karate network using `plot` compared to using `plotly`, there are many connections in `plot` that aren't in `plotly`.

I've given up trying to make this work, visNetwork is an excellent alternative that I've had a much easier time figuring out.  Recommend that for anyone with a similar issue reading this.

Comment: Thanks for the visNetwork suggestion, works like a charm. Was having similar problems with the plotly example, this part in the tutorial is problematic. `x0 = Xn[v0],
    y0 = Yn[v0]` It tries to lookup a vertex name in a numeric vector, which generates some funky results..